# Where can I find the sources for the opinion that gelatin from non kasher animals is permitted?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, halacha-theory

Where can I find the sources on which the opinion that says gelatin from non kasher animals is permitted based on the concept of nifsal me'achilas kelev?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79371/are-pig-bones-and-feather-from-non-kosher-animals-human-hair-human-dried-bone

Comment: https://seforimblog.com/2021/12/gelatin-supposed-retractions-and-abraham-goldstein-part-1/

Answer (score 4):

These three all say some variation of that theme:

- Chaim Ozer Gradinski. Shut Achiezer III:33
- Tzvi Pesach Frank. Har Tzvi, Yoreh Deah 83
- Ovadia Yosef. Yabia Omer, Yoreh Deah, 8:11

Comment: I heard there's a teshuva of Rav Moshe that says this?

Comment: @robev Rav Moshe has two main teshuvot on gelatin (YD 1:37 and YD 2:27) and he rules strictly on this issue.

Comment: @popularis He rules stringently out of doubt though, no? That's very different

Comment: R' Ahron Kotler rules stringently on this (Mishnas R Ahron YD 16:9 and 17:17). See also Tzitz Eliezer V4, letter from Dayan Abramsky who is lenient